# Word or phrase describing preference for written language over spoken language

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

What is a word or phrase describing the prioritization of or preference for written language over spoken language?

Example 1:

> They have a [insert word/phrase here]. They continue to write their language exclusively using a millennia-old literary form that has long diverged from their spoken language.

Example 2:

> Ali learned to write fluently in a dozen languages, but he did not bother to learn how to pronounce most of the words he writes. He has a [insert word/phrase here].

My first guess was "graphological bias," but that doesn't seem correct, as Google phrase match search returns only two results for that phrase.

Comment: *Graphophilia* as opposed to *orality*.

Comment: Perhaps "They have a ***literary sense of language***", might get the idea across - though "literary" has other more commonly understood senses.

Answer (score 1):

That's called **‘graphocentrism’**:

> **Graphocentrism** or **scriptism** is a typically unconscious interpretative bias in which writing is privileged over speech. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphocentrism)]

The opposite is **‘[phonocentrism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonocentrism)’** which is the belief that speech is superior to writing.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind alliteration...

> They have a ***penchant for primitive print***. They continue to write their language exclusively using a millennia-old literary form that has long diverged from their spoken language.

[**penchant**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/penchant) - (n.) - a strong or habitual liking for something or tendency to do something